# Eclipse PDT and .yml file, cannot open?

Tags: php, eclipse, yaml

I am using Symphony framework and I have the default sandbox inside the Eclipse IDE. When I double click schema.yml instead of open in Eclipse it requests Windows to select a program to choose. I am a Visual Studio guy and I do not understand why it doesn't open in Eclipse, what should I do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on the file, select OPEN WITH>Text Editor and it will open in the IDE

Comment: Exact answer I was looking for!

Comment: additionally, you can install en eclipse plugin for YAML editing http://code.google.com/p/yedit/